# how to iterate over inner objects / property in an object

Tags: javascript, object, iteration

I have an object which has inner objects and properties defined like this:

```
var obj = {obj1 : { "prop1" : "nothing", "prop2" : "prop"},
        obj2 : {"prop1" : "nothing", "prop2" : "prop"},
        pr1 : "message",
        pr2 : "mess"
};
```

Normally to iterate every property of an object , the `for .. in` loop can do the trick

```
for (property in obj){
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)){
        console.log(property + "   " + obj[property]);
    }
}
```

the console displayed :

> ```
> obj1 [object Object]
> obj12 [object Object]
> pr1 message
> pr2 mess
> ```

However how to iterate the inner objects (`obj1, obj2`) and their own properties (`prop1,prop2`) ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Recursion is your friend:

```
function iterate(obj) {
    for (var property in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            if (typeof obj[property] == "object")
                iterate(obj[property]);
            else
                console.log(property + "   " + obj[property]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: don't forget to declare `property` locally using `var`!

Comment: thanks very much  ! True if I forget to declare **var property**, property is global

Answer (score 13):

That's great anwsers, although the array cases is not covered, here's my contribution:

```
var getProps = function (obj) {
    for (var property in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property) && obj[property] != null) {
            if (obj[property].constructor == Object) {
                getProps(obj[property]);
            } else if (obj[property].constructor == Array) {
                for (var i = 0; i < obj[property].length; i++) {
                    getProps(obj[property][i]);
                }
            } else {
                console.log(obj[property]);
            }
        }
    }
}
getProps(myObject);
```

Comment: And covering array is especially important when the properties can also be strings - otherwise you would get random garbage as an output, or you would exceed the call stack size. +1 for this

Comment: Just be careful because this method has some issues printing arrays without objects, like: 
array: ["value1", "value2", "value"] or array: [1234, 1234, 1234]. It's required to validate if the elements of the array are objects, otherwise, it's required to only print the value

Answer (score 5):

You can use recursion to achieve that:

```
function Props(obj) {

 function getProps(obj){
  for (var property in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)){
        if (obj[property].constructor == Object) {
           console.log('**Object -> '+property+': ');
           getProps(obj[property]);
        } else {
           console.log(property + " " + obj[property]);
        }
    }
  }
 }
 getProps(obj);
}
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/hg6dU/

Comment: The answer is correct but few minutes later than the 1rst . Nevertheless it's worth vote up.

Comment: Fine with me of course, but maybe you should try testing the `iterate` function of the accepted answer using an array within the object (like `{a:[1,2,3], b:3, c:{a:1,b:1}`}?

Answer (score 5):

To simply display the object structure, I often use: console.log (JSON.stringify (obj))

Comment: .. and to beautify the JSON output, `JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4)`.