# Hide rooms from APS viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am building a digital twin for buildings, but not every user of the application is allowed to see the whole building, but only the part, that he rents. How is it possible to hide rooms and their content from viewer and show only a list of allowed rooms?

I already tried ThreeCSG (see [Rooms with Forge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69928244/rooms-with-forge)), but ThreeCSG does not work with BufferGeometry.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I need a solution working with non rectangular rooms. E.g. room 2 below and it's contents need to be hidden:

```
+---+---+
|   | 2 |
|   +---+
| 1     |
+-------+
```

Comment: How about applying section boxe to the allowed Room? e.g., the space filter of https://youtu.be/aNLFpVgeOVc?t=20

Comment: Does this also work with non rectangular rooms? See my edit of the question.