# Use object property for iteration

Tags: javascript, object, properties, iteration, enumerable

it is possible to use a object property for a "for in"-Iteration in JavaScript?

I want write a Bag-Class like this:

```
var Bag = function () {
  this.elements = {};
}

Bag.prototype.add = function (key, value) {
  this.elements[key] = value;
};

// other methods ...
```

Now i want use objects of this class in a for in iteration:

```
for (var key in myBag) {
  console.log(myBag[key]); // or myBag.get(key);
}
```

It is possible to do this without a helper method like var key in myBag.getAll()?

Comment: How about `for (var key in myBag.elements)`?

Comment: damn, too easy. But i prefer a solution without the ".elements", if it is possible.

Comment: this.elements[key] would be equivalent to this.elements.key (if the key existed), because you're defining elements as an object.. so if elements is an array. Assign it as so: this.elements = [];

in your add use a this.elements.push({"key":key,"val":value});

Comment: wait.. are you trying to expose, assign, and iterate over the properties/members of the object myBag instance?

Comment: I want to iterate over all properties from only one property of the object myBag. Inspired by the enumeration interface of languages like java.

Comment: You can try an [iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) (Firefox only) or an ES6 iterator, but currently your best choice is enumerating `myBag.elements`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the key/value pairs to the instance itself, and create the method as non-enumerable, for example:

```
function Bag() {
}

Object.defineProperty(Bag.prototype, 'add', {
  enumerable: false,
  value: function(k, v) {
    this[k] = v
  }
})

var bag = new Bag
bag.add('a',1)
bag.add('b',2)
bag.add('c',3)

for (var k in bag)
  console.log(k)
//^ a
//  b
//  c
```

Note, that you could also declare the method normally and always loop with `hasOwnProperty` check:

```
for (var k in bag)
  if (bag.hasOwnProperty(k))
    console.log(k)
```

Or another alternative:

```
Object.keys(bag).forEach(function(k) {
  console.log(k)
})
```

Comment: this is interesting.. perhaps you could combine this answer with http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/hg6dU/ which is referenced in this SO Q&A... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432967/how-to-iterate-over-inner-objects-property-in-an-object?rq=1

Comment: nice idea, unfortunately is "add" not assignable ;) if no one has a better idea, i want to use this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this, example is `forEach` but you could make a `map` or a `filter` or whatever.

Javascript

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    function Bag() {
        this.elements = {};
    }

    Bag.prototype = {
        add: function (key, value) {
            this.elements[key] = value;
        },

        forEach: function (fn, thisArg) {
            Object.keys(this.elements).forEach(function (key) {
                fn.call(thisArg, this[key], key, this);
            }, this.elements);
        }
    };


    var myBag = new Bag();

    myBag.add('one', 1);
    myBag.add('two', 2);
    myBag.add('three', 3);

    myBag.forEach(function (item, key, object) {
        console.log(this, item, key, object);
    }, 'hello');
}());
```

Output

```
hello 1 one Object {one: 1, two: 2, three: 3}
hello 2 two Object {one: 1, two: 2, three: 3}
hello 3 three Object {one: 1, two: 2, three: 3}
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/2yCyH/)