# JavaScript-Traversing through object and drawing elements

Tags: javascript

I have a structure like this

```
var div = {
  'id': '',
  div: [{
    'id': '',
    div: [{
      'id': '',
      div: [{
        'id': '',
      }]
    }],
    span: [{
      id:''
    }]
  }],
}
```

I have to parse this object and draw the elements accordingly (nesting as you can see).  I already have a function which draws the elements it only requires the element type i.e 'div'.

Comment: Related: [how to iterate over inner objects / property in an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432967/how-to-iterate-over-inner-objects-property-in-an-object)

Comment: JSON.parse() might help you here..!

Comment: @hemanth: There's no JSON above.

Comment: @jack when you do like this div.div it will show you a array in console with length two.

Comment: My mistake, I have edited