# How to iterate through whole json in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I can have a json object. This object is not the same everytime. It can change dynamically. It can have object of arrays, array of arrays, array of objects anything that follows http://www.json.org/ standard

I want to XML escape each of the leaf level json object.

```
var jsonObject = {};//is not standard will change dynamically

var xmlescape = require('xml-escape');

iterate through each of the json object
   jsonObjectAtParticularLevel = xmlescape(jsonObjectAtParticulatLevel);
```

How do I iterate through the whole json object and change it?

---

I tried to use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`, but I don't think that would be efficient.

```
function replacer(key, value) {
  if (typeof value === "string") {
    return xmlescape(value);
  }
  return value;
}
var newJsonObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonObject, replacer));
```

---

I want to use something like a recursive loop which will iterate through the whole json. But I'm able to figure out how to parse the whole json.

Comment: @Downvoters, Please comment the reason for the downvote. Just downvoting is not appreciated.

Comment: Though I'm not the downvoter, you should be more specific. May be share sample JSON. Also there are many post on SO on how to loop over JSON, so adding generic title can cause misunderstandings

Comment: I think you are confusing json with object. json is a serialized string of an object. (javascript object notation) perhaps your question is ''how do I recursively iterate over a javascript object?"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432967/how-to-iterate-over-inner-objects-property-in-an-object

Answer (score 0):

[JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) with **revival** function should be enough

```
       var object = {"id":"10", "class": [{"child-of-9": "AABC"}, {"9": "a"}]};

        $(function() {
         object = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object), function (k, v) {
             if(typeof v == "string") {
                 return v + "changed";
             }
             return v;
         })
            console.log(JSON.stringify(object));
            alert(JSON.stringify(object));
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let obj = {
   'name': '',
   'age' : ''
       }
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
   console.log(key, '--> List of keys in the object')
})
```