# How to loop on json object array jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

i want to loop on output of json array object and access its elements how to do that ?
thats the  output of json array object after performing query on it

```
Object {0: Object, 1: Object, 3: Object, 5: Object}
0:Object
certificate:""
country:"Egypt"
created_at:"2017-04-26 20:39:22"
description:"  "
end_date:"2017-04-22"
event_id:1
id:1
name:"Project Management"
pic:"4537c00b63a920f5d1a49bd37b01e789.jpg"
1:Object
3:Object
5:Object
```

i tried to write such code but it didnt worked i just accessed first and second elements only . it seems that i didnt write right loop . it refused to access third and fourth element. it has to do something with number written beside it .

```js
var arr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
console.log(arr);

var count = Object.keys(arr).length;
console.log(Object.keys(arr).length);
if (count != 0) {
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    if (arr[i].type == "img")
      var image = document.createElement("img");
    var e = "/storage/" + arr[i].pic.replace("\\", "");
    image.src = e;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the property names in your object are not sequential numbers. There's no `arr[2]` in your object. Your code is designed to loop over an array that has objects in every element, not an object with missing keys.

Use the jQuery `$.each()` function to iterate over an object.

```
var img;
$.each(arr, function(key, obj) {
    if (obj.type == 'img') {
        img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = "/storage/" + obj.pic.replace('\\', '');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to output a Json object for logging purposes:

```
JSON.stringify(your_json_object);
```

Just saw your updates, I think you want to do this:
[how to iterate over inner objects / property in an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432967/how-to-iterate-over-inner-objects-property-in-an-object)

Comment: problem is i want to access all properties not just one