# Looping multilevel Object

Tags: javascript, loops, object, recursion

Assuming we have the following Object, what would be the best way to iterate it up to it's end in order to get the name property for each Object? 
**Please notice**, that the size of the Object may vary and the browsing should be done in this order: a, b, a1, a2, b1, a21, b11, b12 ...

```
var obj = {
  a: {
    name: 'a',
    a1: {
      name: 'a1'
    },
    a2: {
      name: 'a2',
      a21: {
        name: 'a21'
      }
    }
  },

  b: {
    name: 'b'
    b1: {
      name: 'b1',
      b11: {
        name: 'b11'
      },
      b12: {
        name: 'b12'
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: You need to use a recursive function (calls itself). And pass to each time the object in the current level.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to iterate over inner objects / property in an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432967/how-to-iterate-over-inner-objects-property-in-an-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). It is an algorithm which is iterating every level of the tree first and then the next level.

This implementation works with a queue of nodes, that means, to call the function `breadthFirst`, the object/single node must be wrapped in an array.

```js
function breadthFirst(queue) {
    var newQueue = [];
    queue.forEach(function (node) {
        ('name' in node) && console.log(node.name);
        Object.keys(node).forEach(function (k) {
            node[k] && typeof node[k] === 'object' && newQueue.push(node[k]);
        });
    });
    newQueue.length && breadthFirst(newQueue);
}

var object = { a: { name: 'a', a1: { name: 'a1' }, a2: { name: 'a2', a21: { name: 'a21' } } }, b: { name: 'b', b1: { name: 'b1', b11: { name: 'b11' }, b12: { name: 'b12' } } } };

breadthFirst([object]); // a b a1 a2 b1 a21 b11 b12
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Great answer. This is exactly what I was looking for. Couldn't thank you enough.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a `breadth-first` solution which Nina has rightly mentioned. Here is my implementation of it. In this solution, you can store the result in the array and then do `console.log` later.

```js
var obj = {
  a: {
    name: 'a',
    a1: {
      name: 'a1'
    },
    a2: {
      name: 'a2',
      a21: {
        name: 'a21'
      }
    }
  },
  b: {
    name: 'b',
    b1: {
      name: 'b1',
      b11: {
        name: 'b11'
      },
      b12: {
        name: 'b12'
      }
    }
  }
};

var ans = [];
var q = [];
q.push(obj);

function getAllKeys() {
  if (q.length == 0) {
    return;
  }
  var obj = q.shift();

  var keys = Object.keys(obj);
  ans = ans.concat(keys);
  var index = ans.indexOf('name');
  if (index != -1) {
    ans.splice(index, 1);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    if (typeof obj[keys[i]] == 'object') {
      q.push(obj[keys[i]]);
    }

  }
  getAllKeys();
}
getAllKeys();
console.log(ans);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a recursive thing here. You are free to change the console.log to push somewhere or whatever...

```
var obj = {
    a: {
        name: 'a',
        a1: {
            name: 'a1'
        },
        a2: {
            name: 'a2',
            a21: {
                name: 'a21'
            }
        }
    },
        b: {
        name: 'b',
        b1: {
            name: 'b1',
            b11: {
                name: 'b11'
            },
            b12: {
                name: 'b12'
            }
        }
    }
};

var looping = function(obj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        if(typeof obj[keys[i]] === 'string') console.log(obj[keys[i]]);
        else looping(obj[keys[i]]);
    }
}

looping(obj);
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't provide the output OP is looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple recursive function to get all the `name` properties in **breadth-first** order. I'm using a helper, `pairs`, that makes it easier to process the key-value pairs provided by each object. From there, it's a simple case analysis for how the recursive function should respond:

- base case – return the accumulator
- key is `name`, append `value` to the accumulator
- value is an object, add `pairs` of `value` to the list of pairs to process
- default case - do nothing and process the next pair

This answer differs from others in that there is no side effect from running it. Instead of hard coding some behavior in the `loop` function itself, `loop` returns an array of `name` property values that you can then do with whatever you wish.

```js
const pairs = o =>
  Object.keys(o).map(k => ({key: k, value: o[k]}))
  
const loop = o => {
  const aux = (acc, [x,...xs]) => {
    if (x === undefined)
      return acc
    else if (x.key === 'name')
      return aux([...acc, x.value], xs)
    else if (Object(x.value) === x.value)
      return aux(acc, xs.concat(pairs(x.value)))
    else
      return aux(acc, xs)
  }
  return aux([], pairs(o))
}

const obj = { a: { name: 'a', a1: { name: 'a1' }, a2: { name: 'a2', a21: { name: 'a21' } } }, b: { name: 'b', b1: { name: 'b1', b11: { name: 'b11' }, b12: { name: 'b12' } } } }
  
console.log(loop(obj))
// [ 'a', 'b', 'a1', 'a2', 'b1', 'a21', 'b11', 'b12' ]
```

Alternatively, you could implement `loop` using a generator such that you could act on the values *while* iterating. Let me know if this interests you and I'll do a write up.

---

**Edit**

Original answer processed the object in the incorrect order. The above code now answers the question properly ^_^

Comment: funny, all other answers, as yours as well uses depth first, which is not asked ...

Comment: Oh wups! I wasn't paying enough attention. I'll try to fix it when I wake up ^_^ thx Nina

Comment: @NinaScholz thanks for catching this. I updated the answer <3

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [breadth-first traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search):

```js
// Breadh-first object traversal:
function traverse(...objs) {
  for (let obj of objs) {
    let next = Object.values(obj).filter(val => val && typeof val === 'object');
    objs.push(...next);
  }
  return objs;
}

// Example:
let obj = {
  a:{name:"a",a1:{name:"a1"},a2:{name:"a2",a21:{name:"a21"}}},
  b:{name:"b",b1:{name:"b1",b11:{name:"b11"},b12:{name:"b12"}}}
};

for (let child of traverse(obj)) {
  if (child.name) console.log(child.name);
}
```