# How do I loop all Firebase children in React Native?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

***ANSWER AT BOTTOM OF POST***
(ALSO SEE @soutot ANSWER)

I have successfully gained text output from my `Firebase` code and so I know it works. Now I need to loop all the children in `Firebase`. Coming from swift, the way to do it is to store each item on a tempObject then append that to an array. Then you can simply use that array any way you like. This doesn't seem to work with `JavaScript`, or I'm doing something wrong. The fully functional FB code I now have is:

```
componentDidMount(){
    let child = "" 
    var ref = firebase.database().ref("testCategory");

    ref.once("value")
    .then(function(snapshot) {
        child = snapshot.child("test1/testHeader").val() 
        this.setState( {    
            child
        })
    }.bind(this)); 
}
```

I can then successfully print this in console or in `<Text>`. Now, the problem I'm having is looping all children, adding them to an array, then using that array to display the data. In my head, this is how it should work:

```
componentDidMount(){
    let child = "" 
    var ref = firebase.database().ref("testCategory");

    ref.once("value")
    .then(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
           let tempObject = MyFirebase
           tempObject.testHeader = 
           childSnapshot.val() 

           myArray.append(tempObject) //or .push???
        })
        this.setState( {    //PASSING VARIABLE TO STATE
            child   
        })
    }.bind(this)); //BINDING TO SET STATE
}
```

I know that this is obviously wrong. Creating an object like that doesn't even work... `MyFirebase` -class looks like this:

```
render() {
let testHeader = ""
let testText = ""   
)
}
```

My `Firebase` database looks like this: 
    [image: FB DB]
(I ignored subText for now)

All suggestions are much appreciated :)

***WORING CODE***

```
 //FIREBASE CODE 
componentDidMount(){
    const ref = firebase.database().ref("testCategory");

    ref.once("value")
    .then(function(snapshot) {
        const categories = []

        //LOOPING EACH CHILD AND PUSHING TO ARRAY
        snapshot.forEach(item => {

            const temp = item.val();
            categories.push(temp);
            return false;
        });

        this.setState( {    //PASSING VARIABLE TO STATE
            child,
            categories
        })
    }.bind(this)); //BINDING TO SET STATE
}
```

Comment: In case of Realtime Database, data is stored as JSON, so your question seems to be: [how to recursively iterate over an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432967/how-to-iterate-over-inner-objects-property-in-an-object).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the code you provided, it looks like it works until this point

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("testCategory");

    ref.once("value")
    .then(function(snapshot) {
```

Am I correct?

From this point, if you add a `console.log(snapshot.val())` it might print an array of objects, something like this:
`[ { test1: { testHeader: 'FirstHeader', testText: 'FirstText' } }, { test2: { testHeader: 'SecondSub', testText: 'SecondSub } }]`

Right?

If so, you can for example store this snapshot into your state and then consume this state in your render method. Something like this:

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref('testCategory');

ref.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
  this.setState({ categories: snapshot.val() });
});
```

Then in your render method:

```
const { categories } = this.state;

categories.map(category => <Text>{category.testHeader}</Text>)
```

The result in your screen should be:
FirstHeader
SecondSub

Let me know if this helped

Some links that might explain more about es6 codes I used in this example:

array map `categories.map(...)`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

object destructuring `const { categories } = this.state`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

const instead of var `const ref = ...`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

setState: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

arrow function `(snapshot) => ...`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Some about firebase snapshots: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your help. Didn't quite get it to work as array tended to store JSON data instead of array variables, if that makes sense. Maybe I misunderstood some part of your post. Anyway, was helped alot by your post and got it right using forEach. See my post above. :)

Comment: Great, nice to know you could handle it. Looking at your code, it might have a little issue in the future. JS works sync, if you have a large list of items, your code might call ```setState``` before your ```forEach``` looped through all your items. Maybe you'll need it to be async. To do so, you need to use ```async/await``` to tell your code to wait until ```forEach``` is finished to then go to next step. Something like: ```.then(async function(snapshot) (...) await snapshot.forEach (...)```  Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll definitely take that into consideration! :)